# @font-face src: url(...) could not figure out context path, which could be a variable

Tags: css, font-face

My css file has this custom font using absolute path for URL. It works perfectly in case of default context path which is empty:

```
@font-face {
    src: url('/font/myfont-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}
```

The web application is deployed either in jBoss or Tomcat, and the context path is configurable. Below "ABC" can be anything.

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>ABC</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

With context path other than empty, my custom font could no longer be loaded, since it does not know how to add "context path" to the "URL" for font location.

I am getting 404 error when loading this custom font when context path is set. 
The reason for 404 is that it is trying to load via 
    http://www.example.com/font/myfont-Regular.woff

While it should be loading from:
    http://www.example.com/ABC/font/myfont-Regular.woff

But "ABC" (context path) is configurable at client site, and I could not hardcode it in the css file.
I have tried "c:url" tag in the css file but it could not be evaluated. (It is understandable) . css file would not be aware of JSP scriplets either.

I would like to find a way to load the custom font by being "context path" aware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is instead of external css file, use internal stylesheet syntax inside the JSP file in order to be context path aware. For example, embed below section in your "head" section in your JSP. "c:url" would then properly resolve the path including context.

```
<style> 
   @font-face {
     ....
     src: url("<c:url value='/font/myfont-Regular.woff'/>") format('woff');
   }
</style>
```

Now to improve the re-usability of above internal style, one more trick is to use a JSP(or JSPF) file whose sole content is above internal style. Then it could be included wherever necessary. It has to have an extension of ".jsp" or ".jspf" in order to be "context aware" though.